# Logout confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have redirect to logout.php

```
<a class="menu_button" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

On logout.php I just destroy session and redirect user back to login.

What I need is that when user click on menu_button Logout, to display dialog box asking him to confirm that he wants to logout.

I know I can do it via php new page, but think this is more elegant.

I have this:

```
<a class="menu_button" href="logout.php" onClick="return confirm('Sure to logout?');">Logout</a>
```

But browser popup window is just ugly..

EDIT:

I used this, and it's not working....

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery/js/jquery.easy-confirm-dialog.js"></script>
<script>
$(".customDialog").easyconfirm({dialog: $("#question")});
</script>
```

body

```
<a href="?confirm=true" class="customDialog">Test with custom confirm dialog</a>
  <div class="dialog" id="question"><img src="question.png" alt="" />Do you want to continue?</div>
```

Comment: Can I style that popup window at all?

Comment: Sorry my question was a little vague/incomplete... answers below cover to what I was referring (jquery ui).

Comment: No, until now it is impossible. Probably in future when browser vendors will realize practical shadow dom API... Dreams:)

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "modal", or essentially, a floating div styled using CSS that sits atop your site, optionally with a 100%x100% background later to stop users from interacting with the site behind the modal. You do not *need* jQuery to do this.

Comment: You has all set for ui usage but at the end using easy confirm, choose one you prefer. From the provided update code JavaScript looks good. But I can't see CSS for easy confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you with familiar [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (and more specifically [jQuery ui](http://jqueryui.com/)? They can allow you to create fairly good looking dialogs (by which I mean you can do pretty much anything with them that you can with your page - in an easy way).

I would also recommend [jquery easy confirmation dialogs](http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/) plugin.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: Well isn't this embarrassing ... Sorry about that :L I think I need some sleepy sleepy time (or coffee at the very least).

Answer (score 1):

You may adapt jQuery UI dialog. It is very easy to use.
Actually, try http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: It is indeed very simple, you got everything in box. CSS/JavaScript/sample markup, skins set. And it quietly flexible in terms customization.